# How to modify responsive timeline?

Tags: css, responsive-design, sass

http://codepen.io/kjohnson/pen/azBvaE

My friend and I are thinking of using that timeline in our website. But the problem is we've 5 sections that needs to be added to timeline, whereas the original timeline have only 3 sections.

I've tried to add two more sections to that code, but it's losing its shape and responsiveness.

Is it possible to extend that timeline and maintain its responsiveness?

HTML

```
  <!-- STEPS -->
 <section id="Steps" class="steps-section">

<h2 class="steps-header">
  Responsive Semantic Timeline
</h2>

<div class="steps-timeline">

  <div class="steps-one">
    <img class="steps-img" src="http://placehold.it/50/3498DB/FFFFFF" alt="" />
    <h3 class="steps-name">
      Semantic
    </h3>
    <p class="steps-description">
      The timeline is created using negative margins and a top border.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="steps-two">
    <img class="steps-img" src="http://placehold.it/50/3498DB/FFFFFF" alt="" />
    <h3 class="steps-name">
      Relative
    </h3>
    <p class="steps-description">
       All elements are positioned realtive to the parent. No absolute positioning.
    </p>
  </div>

  <div class="steps-three">
    <img class="steps-img" src="http://placehold.it/50/3498DB/FFFFFF" alt="" />
    <h3 class="steps-name">
      Contained
    </h3>
    <p class="steps-description">
       The timeline does not extend past the first and last elements.
    </p>
  </div>

</div><!-- /.steps-timeline -->
```

CSS

```
$outline-width: 0;
$break-point: 500px;

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic);

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
body {
  font-family: lato;
}

$gray-base:     #999999;
$brand-primary: #3498DB; //Zen Blue

.section-header {
  color: $brand-primary;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}


.steps-header {
  @extend .section-header;
  margin-bottom: 20px;  
  text-align: center;
}
.steps-timeline {
  outline: 1px dashed rgba(red, $outline-width);

  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    border-left: 2px solid $brand-primary;
    margin-left: 25px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    border-top: 2px solid $brand-primary;
    padding-top: 20px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-left: 16.65%;
    margin-right: 16.65%;
  }

  &:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
}
.steps-one,
.steps-two,
.steps-three {
  outline: 1px dashed rgba(green, $outline-width);

  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    margin-left: -25px;
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;  
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
.steps-one,
.steps-two {
  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
.steps-one {
  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    margin-left: -16.65%;
    margin-right: 16.65%;
  }
}
.steps-two {

}
.steps-three {
  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    margin-bottom: -100%;
  }
  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    margin-left: 16.65%;
    margin-right: -16.65%;
  }
}

.steps-img {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%; 

  @media screen and (max-width: $break-point) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
  }
}

.steps-name,
.steps-description {
  margin: 0;
}
.steps-name {
  @extend .section-header;

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
.steps-description {
  overflow: hidden;

  @media screen and (min-width: $break-point) {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your steps are set to 33% width, if you're using 5 elements, change it to 20%. You'd benefit from attempting to debug your code first before asking

Comment: I've also seen your edit. You need to attempt a bit more in terms of debugging your own code. Inspect stuff and see whats breaking where and why. SO isn't for people to write the code for you bud

Comment: there's an answer given below with code sample; is this question still open/unsolved or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you a novice I'd recommend you **LEARN** first. Copy templates/snippets is good to save your time when you **know** what you are doing.

I found a perfect tutorial for you [here](https://codyhouse.co/gem/horizontal-timeline/)

Just to emphasize that's my opinion, I hope it helps in a certain way..

EDIT: If still want to develop in that way [here's](http://codepen.io/abhisharma2/pen/vEKWVo) a codepen snippet with a fully responsive horizontal timeline. Just have to put more `<li>` inside the `<ul>`